# Newly added options in existing select control is not reflecting in view in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, html-select

I have initialized a list of options for my DDL and later I want to add some more options to the same DDL.
In the console, it shows that those options are added but in view, it's not reflecting the changes.

Below is my code and explanations:

1. Initialized the list (Select with optgroup)

```
this.optList1 = [
    {
        "RuleId": 104,
        "RuleName": "Rule 104",
        "IsActive": true,
    },
    {
        "RuleId": 105,
        "RuleName": "Rule 105",
        "IsActive": true,
    }
];

this.optGroup = [];
const obj1 = {
    name: 'Group 1',
    rule: this.optList1
};
this.optGroup.push(obj1);
```

2. Later in some function call I'm adding some more options in the same DDL

```
this.optList2 = [
    {
        "RuleId": 111,
        "RuleName": "Rule 111",
        "IsActive": true,
    },
    {
        "RuleId": 112,
        "RuleName": "Rule 112",
        "IsActive": true,
    }
];
const obj2 = {
    name: 'Group 2',
    rule: this.optList2
};
this.optGroup.push(obj2);
```

Here is HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="rules" multiple [compareWith]="compareRule">
        <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of optGroup" [label]="group.name">
            <ng-container *ngIf="group.name == 'Group 1'">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let rule of group.rule" [value]="rule">{{rule.RuleName}}</mat-option>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="group.name == 'Group 2'">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let rule of group.rule" [value]="rule">{{rule.RuleName}}</mat-option>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**All the options are showing in the console but not reflecting in view.**

Comment: Could be an issue with the markup, could you please provide that as well

Comment: @AdityaMenon added markup as well.

Comment: @OMPRAKASH How is  `optGroup` used in template?

Comment: @OMPRAKASH Does doing `this.optGroup = [...this.optGroup, obj2]` work for you?

Comment: try to recreate your array. You are pushing new element but it is the same array (same reference), so angular may not consider this as a change. 
Test this: `this.optGroup = [...this.optGroup, obj2]`

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @OMPRAKASH can you please share some example to test with?

Comment: I think @QuentinFonck is right, please retry his solution.
Alternatively you can inject into your constructor ChangeDetectorRef and start a manually detectchanges after the push.

-------

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

yourFunction() {
  this.optGroup.push(obj2);
  this.cd.detectChanges();
}

Answer (score 2):

You must be doing something wrong when putting your code together.
I took you code exactly how it is and created a [live demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jslmo4?file=src/app/select-optgroup-example.ts) , take a look maybe it is gonna help you find the problem.
Everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You should verify how the changes for this component are working. In case you have not defined any strategy for this you can force the component to update the view with something like this:

In your TS

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, ViewRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ) {}

updateDOM() {
        if (this.changeDetectorRef && !(this.changeDetectorRef as ViewRef).destroyed) {
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        }
    }
```

and then you can use that updateDOM method after the push.